# (Unity) Is there a way to animate Line Renderer without code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm prototyping a 2D space shooter, and i wanted a secondary special attack that creates a laser, completely kinematic, coming out of the ship's front. I've done the laser using Line Renderer and the Bloom Post Processing effect.

So I was wondering if it is possible to animate the line renderer on the animator.
I've tried to do it but it seems that the animator, as far as I can see on my Unity 2019.2.17f1 version, that it only appears to allow animations for the Line Renderer's material-related stuff, not related to the position array (curve), aside from the Width multiplier property, which I also need but isnt sufficient for the animation

Maybe I'm missing a name but it seems that you cant really modify the parameters if it's not via code.

Any ideas?

Comment: line renderer animation is not done a model animation with vertex movement + bones + weights. It is done modifying the line renderer points which is a `Vector3[]`, so I think its not possible to do it without code afaik. What's the problem with doing it with code?

Comment: thinking of it that way, i did animate particle system with animator, hence the question of why wouldnt i be able to animate line renderer too. no problem with code whatsoever though

Comment: Why you just using LineRenderer, if it doesn't fits your needs? LineRenderer is the tool to create mesh. If you need only the laser, I assume, your generated mesh is just a single quad (if your laser ray is not bent). Ok, if the ray is reflected, you can use two quads. You can fully control simple quad with animator. Or, if you are familiar with particles, you can use particle system for it. Also, if you need some sophisticated behaviour, you can parent your ray (both particle or quad) to some root object, to ease the control:

Comment: This way you'll have the ray, animated in local coordinates, and the root object to manipulate - aim you ray, or attach it to laser gun - rotate and move it freely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is there isnt, and i switched to particle system for a more simple use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if or why it is not possible but most probably it is due to the fact that it is an array unlike all the properties you usually animate which are single values.

What you could do though if it is only supposed to animate e.g. the end point have a component like e.g.

```csharp
public class LaserController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer line;

    public bool enableLaser;
    public Vector3 endPoint;

    private void LateUpdate ()
    {
        line.enabled = enableLaser;
        line.SetPosition(1, endpoint);
    }
}
```

And simply animate the fields of that one.

Comment: Ill try this out and come some time later for an answer, thanks!